# Inexplicable hang crashes in Microsoft Store App

Tags: javascript, uwp, microsoft-edge

I have JavaScript UWP app (for Xbox) in the Microsoft Store that for months has been reporting back to the crash report a series of cryptic errors I can find absolutely no information about online. Just these six errors (and more like them occasionally) constitute 81% of failure hits. I have been trying but unable to reproduce these, which isn't surprising given that 99.5% of all sessions in the app are crash-free.

```
moapplication_hang_cfffffff_{APPID}!hang_navigation
moapplication_hang_80000003_{APPID}!hang_navigation
moapplication_hang_80000003_{APPID}!hang_activation
moapplication_hang_cfffffff_{APPID}!hang_activation
moapplication_hang_cfffffff_{APPID}!hang_quiesce
```

Taking a close look at the various stack traces, the most common thing I see is that something happens with the message loop of the dispatcher for the window first, which I am guessing indicates the app is either first opened or is being foregrounded, edgehtml.dll then attempts to do some rendering before hitting HasAnyPaintObjectNeedsPreRenderNotification, and a few steps down the line a crash happens.

[image]

My best guess for all of this is that these are bugs in the Edge browser and not inside my application, but without any info, it is difficult to confirm. Occasionally, I do see Chakra.dll in the stack trace right before a crash, but these almost always seem to involve a messaging loop for rendering.

Does anybody have any experience with errors of these kind and any additional information to offer? Is there a potential code fix?

Comment: Hi, since you can not reproduce this issue, it will be hard to investigate this issue without the dump file, I will recommend you report this issue in the Windows 10 Feedback Hub app, it will get the trace to further investigation.

Comment: Yeah, I think that is part of the reason why there is no answer whatsoever yet because barely a handful of similar questions have been asked of Microsoft with all the same response. The response is either that they posted the question in the wrong forum or should pay Microsoft for an answer.

Comment: I am sorry, I can't analyze your problem based on the existing information. Your problem requires a professional to analyze your dump file. You can ask for help from relevant personnel.